# Backslash escaping is not working in Python

Tags: python

I want Python interpreter to show me `\'` as a calculated value. I tried typing `"\\'"` and it returned me the same thing. If I try `"\'"` then the backslash is not shown anymore after I hit return. How do I get it to show the backslash like this after I hit return- `\'` ?

#### Additional question

This is exact question I am not understanding: 
Expression -->

> 'C' +  + 'D'

Calculated Value -->

> 'C\'D'

Find the missing literal

Comment: What do you mean as a calculated value? You mean to print `\'`?

Answer (score 7):

Here are two ways to get `\'`:

```
>>> print("\\'")
\'
>>> print(r"\'")
\'
```

#### Discussion

```
>>> print("\'")
'
```

The above prints out a single `'` because an escaped `'` is just a `'`.

```
>>> print(r"\'")
\'
```

The above prints the backslash because `r` prevents interpretation of escapes.

```
>>> print("\\'")
\'
```

The above prints `\'` because an escaped backslash is a backslash.

#### Other forms of strings

Using unicode-strings (under python2):

```
>>> print(u"\\'")
\'
>>> print(ur"\'")
\'
```

Using byte-codes (also python 2):

```
>>> print(b"\\'")
\'
>>> print(br"\'")
\'
```

#### Answer for additional question

Using the principles described above, the answer for the additional question is:

```
>>> print('C' + "\\'" 'D')
C\'D
>>> print('C' + r"\'" 'D')
C\'D
```

Comment: Three ways. There's also `print(u"\\'")`.

Comment: But it's not. Unicode vs. ASCII. While Python may internally use Unicode, unless you have the particular indicators, the strings you send to it are ASCII. `u` is similar, in this sense, as `r` in that it's telling Python how to interpret the quoted section.

Answer (score 0):

`print("\'")`

repr of a string will never put out a single backslash. repr smartly picks quotes to avoid backslashes. You can get a \' to come out if you do something like '\'"'